# Rename File in IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage

I need to rename a file in the IsolatedStorage. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't appear to anyway in native C# to do it (there might be in native Win32, but I don't know).

What you could do is open the existing file and copy it to a new file and delete the old one. It would be slow compared to a move, but it might be only way.

```
var oldName = "file.old"; var newName = "file.new";

using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using (var readStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(oldName, FileMode.Open, store))
using (var writeStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(newName, FileMode.Create, store))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
{
  writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: I suppose it is only slow if the file is really big. Maybe a couple of MB should be irrelevant. Going to try it. Thanks Samuel

Comment: Works great! No noticeable overhead.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the copy to a new file, then delete the old file method, starting with Silverlight 4 and .NET Framework v4, IsolatedStorageFile exposes MoveFile and MoveDirectory methods.

Answer (score 1):

Perfectly execute this piece of code

```
string oldName="oldName";
string newName="newName";
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(oldName);
await file.RenameAsync(newName);
```

Comment: This answer uses the new WinRT APIs, and not IsolatedStorage, as requested by the OP