# How to change Directory Name and file name in IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-7

Say I have created a few Directories in IsolatedStorage. Here are my problems:

1) How do I change the name of the Directory in IsoloatedStorage? 
2) What happens to the files stored in the directory which I have change the name.
3) How do I change the file name that stored in Isolatedstorage Example :
   MyCity.txt to FunCity.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to copy the files and write them again with a new name as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736085/rename-file-in-isolatedstorage). You can then delete the old file/directory using the [DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletefile%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) or [DeleteDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.deletedirectory%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) methods.

If you're creating a Mango app, then you have access to the [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.movefile%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) and [MoveDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.movedirectory%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: Using old wp7 version. People are saying wait til the Mango RTM version for development. Thank for the filename changing method. But There is no Directory name changing method. I need this for pre-mango version for  case1. Change directory name where there is no file in it. case 2. Change directory name where there r files in it. Thanks

Comment: @MilkBottle - 1) Simply create a new directory and delete the old one. 2) You'll have to think about the order you want to do this is in to get the most efficiency. You can't rename a directory, but you can create a new one. So create a new directory and copy (using the code in the link above) your old files within that directory to the newly created directory. Then delete the old directory. As for Mango, I was just putting that statement for completeness. If you create a Mango app now, you won't be able to submit it yet anyway.

Comment: Thank u very much. It seems it is very messy when come to deleting directory with files( more than 10). So, I have to copy all the files to new Directory FIRST till finish then i can delete the old directory. Work on it now. We report back. Thanks