# Have contacts in address book of windows phone unique identificator?

Tags: c#, database, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, contacts

I store data of contacts in local database. But if user change name, for examle, my app make new record in database. How I can update new name in database without adding new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is about renaming a file in Isolated Storage.
If so please have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736085/rename-file-in-isolatedstorage)